# Find and Replace item in Scala collection

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Let's say I have a list:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I want to replace all/first items that satisfy a predicate, I know the following way to do it: (e.g. replace any number that is even with -1)

```
val filteredList = list.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 % 2 == 0)

val onlyFirst = list.updated(filteredList.head._2, -1)

val all = for (i <- list) yield if (i % 2 == 0) -1 else i
```

Is there any collection function or nice Scala way that helps in this situation and has a **good performance**?

I also want to keep the order, so I don't want to use `filterNot` and add other items to the list like: (it's also not efficient)

```
val onlyFirst = list.filterNot(_ % 2 != 0) ::: list.filter(_ % 2 == 0).map(x => -1)
```

Comment: @JimN map has problem for just the first one

Answer (score 20):

Simple & efficient:
Replace all items

```
list.map( x => if (x % 2 == 0) -1 else x )
```

Replace one item

```
val index = list.indexWhere( _ % 2 == 0 )
list.updated(index, -1)
```

Comment: What language is this? :) You should also remove `then`. But it's great, simple and effecient