# Replace elements in List by condition

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I have a pretty much large `val s: List[Int] = //...`, a function `f: Int => Boolean` and a function `transform: Int => Int`.

***The problem***: I want to create another `List[Int]` such that all elements `e: Int` of the `s: List[Int]` such that `f(e) = true` are replaced with `transform(e)`.

I looked at cats-mtl [`FunctorEmpty`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-mtl/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/mtl/FunctorEmpty.scala) (to adhere to functional programming style), but it does not seem to work in my case. Maybe some `cats`/`scalaz` data structures can be useful here? Or any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788185/find-and-replace-item-in-scala-collection

Comment: If you don't want transform then you want to keep same or you want to remove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s.map{ e => if(f(e)) transform(e) else e }
```

Comment: Oh... you are exactly right. Thanks. I thought of much more complicated cats-based solution. Damn :(

Answer (score 0):

`List(1, 2, 3).map(fn)` creates a new list which might be not exactly want you need, especially if input is large.

Alternative solution would be to map on view `List(1, 2, 3).view.map(...)` without creating a new list and only "materialize" results when you need them